# How does Schema class access methods from other classes

Tags: laravel

When creating migrations We use the function Schema::create,but If You look inside Schema class it doesn't have this method, it belongs to another class.

Answer (score 1):

The `Schema` is a Facade. Based on the laravel documentation: `a facade is a class that provides access to an object from the container`.

I am not very knowledgable about Facade. You can read more about this here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades

So basically the `Schema` facade uses the `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder` class.